# WordPress Guternberg Content For React Native

Tags: javascript, api, content

I am creating react native mobile app first time. I use WordPress as a WordPress service. Everything is OK excerpt **WordPress content** from api. As you know, WordPress response **Guternberg content block** like below example.
[image: wordpress json content response]

Here are some of things that I found,

- I could use WebView, but I am not sure that I would be good looking to convert this content to WebView.
- Another solutions, I would filter and remove all html tags except ***`basic html tags like <b>, <i>, <ul>, <li>, <p>`*** in wordpress before API response. So, it would be good looking. And then I would use [react-native-render-html](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-render-html) package to show the content in react native.

**Please give me how you did do that like this content in react native?**

Comment: The output of Gutenberg is just HTML. Unless you need to edit it, there’s nothing special about it compared to any other block of HTML. So this is really just a react native question about displaying HTML content. Not anything to do with WordPress specifically. You’d be better off asking at stackoverflow.com.

Comment: isn't this just asking how to display HTML content in a react native UI? I don't see why this question should be WordPress specific, you should ask this on stackoverflow instead. Also recommendations are off topic here if it's a library you're looking for